# shlock: link(/Volumes/Transcend/flutter/bin/cache/shlock10587, /Volumes/Transcend/flutter/bin/cache/.upgrade_lock): Operation not supported

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This error occurs when i run `flutter run` command from the terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting flutter sdk from your pc and download and install it again.

This solved my problem.